# cloning a complete tr and renaming the input fields to unique

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am closing a complete tr and i know i searched through this site and google to find an answer to my question but could not locate exactly, i am doing a cloning, so far so good, it works, i have tried following to find the length of the table and add the variable count to it, but it does not seems to be working:

Here is my piece of code

```
var $table = $('table#myTable');

var $CLONED_ROW = $table.find('tr#tdmyclone').clone();
```

> var count = $table.find('tr#tdmyclone').length;

```
$CLONED_ROW.find(".select2-container").remove();
$CLONED_ROW.find('.createNewItemTag').remove();
$CLONED_ROW.find('td').last().append(
    '<a class="removeItem" href="javascript:void(0);">Remove</a>');

$table.on('click', '.createNewItemTag',  function() {
    count++;
    var $row = $(this).parents('tr:first'),
        $newRow = $CLONED_ROW.clone();
        $newRow.find('.qty').val(0);
        $newRow.insertAfter($row);
```

> $row.find("input.qty").each(function(){
>               $(this).attr({
>                     id: $(this).attr("id") + count,
>                     name: $(this).attr("name") + count
>                 });
>             });

```
});
```

the code in the blockquote is the one which i had added to rename the name and id fields:

but when i run the code, i get the **names** as: `quantity23` for the first field and then `quantity` for all the cloned elements.

i am doing something fishy here but do not know what exactly.

Comment: first thing after `.clone` you have to `.removeAttr('id')`

Comment: u mean to removeattr and then do an add

Comment: This is what I mean. Remove id attr from clone and set new one. ID should be unique in a document.

Comment: i added this `$row.find("input.qty").each(function(){
  $(this).removeattr('id');
  $(this).removeattr('name');
        $(this).attr({
    id: $(this).attr("id") + count,
    name: $(this).attr("name") + count
   });
  });` but thatis now removing the complete element from it, and complete input  field